# Could not find the remote repository - but Stash is accessible in the browser

Tags: git, vpn, hosts

I want to share a strange behaviour I experienced in two companies. Both companies' code is hosted on Stash or Bitbucket servers and thus is accessible either on the browser at `stash.company.com` and via `git` CLI at `git.company.com`. When in VPN I found I could see their code on Stash, but if I tried to `fetch` some commits Git would complain that

```
could not read from remote repository [etc etc]
```

I couldn't figure out why this happened, as when I was in the companies' network the resources were accessible and I didn't change Git configurations (private keys, URLs or the like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I looked into it with a tech from one of the companies and found out that my PC had `hosts` entries for the resolution of `stash.company.com` but not `git.company.com`. Adding the entry for Git solved the problem for me. It is possible that in the local network the URL was resolved by the network's local DNS which is not accessible via VPN.